# magento xampp missing extension sodium

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, xampp, windows

I have installed xampp and trying to install magento 2 via command line,

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://project.magento.com" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento" --db-user="magento" --db-password="asdasd" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="coderemail@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123456" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

and I have also enabled the libraries in php.ini, however my php.in code looks like this,

```
extension=soap
extension=sockets
extension=sodium
extension=sqlite3
extension=xsl
extension=intl
```

but whenever i try to run the install command it shows me the error,

```
[Progress: 1 / 1319]
Required extensions check...

In Installer.php line 546:

  Missing following extensions: 'sodium'
```

I have tried re-installing everything, tried running everything as an administrator, I have also run elasticsearch.bat in background but nothing worked.

can anyone please guide me resolving this issue.

Comment: make sure your terminal php version and your directory "php.ini" version is same